# Impossible to upload pdf on Gdrive subfolders with Python using service account

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I created a flask project which stores a pdf on google drive. The user simpliy drags a pdf over a DIV, and flask uploads the file to Drive using a service account. The upload works fine, but the file uploads in the root folder and not in subfolders. The service account creates a delegate object to enter in gdrive, with the credentials of the owner of files and folders, but it is impossible to upload a file into any subfolder, and it is impossible to read the contents of the folders too.

Does service accounts require any particular permissions to read and write into subfolders?

Regards, Fabio

```
def gauth(id_dipartimento):
   d={}
   json_url = os.environ['SERVICE-ACCOUNT.json']
   scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
   credentials = erviceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_url, scopes=scopes)
## The service account creates ua delegated object with current user credentals
delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated(<CURRENT_USER>)
http_auth = delegated_credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
return http_auth 

def upload_file():
    http_auth = gauth()
    drive_service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)

    folder_id = <folder_id_here>


    body = {
        'name': filename,
        'mimeType': mime_type,
        'useDomainAdminAccess':True,
        'parents':folder_id
    }

    media = MediaFileUpload(filepath,
                            mimetype=mime_type,
                            resumable=True)

    file = drive_service.files().create(body=body,
                                        media_body=media,
                                        fields='id,originalFilename').execute()

    new_permission = {
      'type': "anyone",
      'role': "reader",
    }

    try:
        drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=file["id"], body=new_permission).execute()
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
```

Comment: IIRC permission is not granted to child directories by default. If you're not able to find in the docs, look for a method to list all directories inside the parent directory.  If specific authorisation is required, I don't think the API is even able to see the other directories exist so you may get an empty list. That would confirm it.

Comment: Thank you roganjosh, at this point what could be a workaround? have I to create a Google script in the root directory which moves the files into subfolder?

Comment: Firstly, was I correct in my recall of the issue? I have never used the API directly, only wrapper libraries, and there is no work-around that I'm aware of in those (`gspread` etc.) - you would need to give permission explicitly to every directory. I'm not sure with the raw API.

Comment: When I upload a file in the root using google API it can be listed, but if I move a pdf from a subfolder to the root directory it cannot be listed at all, system return "404 not found error". Why this difference? Certainly it's a permission problem, which permission could I change or set?

Comment: Haven't personally tried this yet. Try to [move the files between folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#moving_files_between_folders) after a successful upload. This method is supported and has implementation of Python.

Comment: Yes I considered that too, but I have no access to subfolders, although the delegated objects uses the owner's privileges, so I can't move the file. Must be a setting to change but who knows what is it? Google documentation is very dispersive sometimes.

Comment: I read    [this guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en)   too, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

One issue is fixed, I had simply to log to the admin console and follow the instructions described in the [service account page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) "Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account".

Then I selected the scopes according to the page [About authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth)

I have still problems when I try to load a file into a subfolder, the file  goes into root folder

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understood how to load files into subfolders too. The 'parents' metadata propety takes a list of folders, it means that a file will be uploaded in all the folders of the list at the same time.

The files are created with the same ID, so when I run  drive_service.files().delete(fileId=id_file).execute() the file will be removed from every folder it was uploaded to.

In another thread I read that it's necessary to provide the "kind" property too, something like that:

[{"id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","kind": "drive#file"},{"id":"YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY","kind": "drive#file"}]

but it didn't work for me, but probably I misunderstood. A simple list object with the IDs of the folder is required, as shown below.

```
folder_id = [folder1, folder2, folder3]


body = {
    'name': filename,
    'mimeType': mime_type,
    'useDomainAdminAccess':True,
    'parents':folder_id
}
```

Hope this will help somenone who uses Google Drive API for the first time.

Fabio