# Google Drive API Folder Creation and upload files by Service account in Google Drive Failed in PHP after 5 hours

Tags: google-drive-api, subdirectory

Environment: PHP

Working with folders and files: 
I created a folder and 4 sub folders within that folder in my google drive.

Google DRIVE API

1)Create a new console project and automatically enable the Drive API
   2)Service account: Create Service account and download the configuration file.

```
Install the Google Client Library.
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

I shared these folder and 4 sub folders with service account.

Expected Result: Folders and files should be create in sub Folders.

Actual Result: 
5 hours it works properly but after completed 5 hours day 404 error updated in error log.

Comment: You can check this answer of the OP in the related SO post regarding [Uploading Gdrive subfolders with Python using service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527336/impossible-to-upload-pdf-on-gdrive-subfolders-with-python-using-service-account). I think you can get an idea from there.

Comment: Great post but it is still not working using the turnaround proposed! thanks